# rJava can be installed, but fails to load

Tags: r, statistics

I have installed the package `rJava`. However, when wanting to use the package I get an error:

```
> install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/rJava_0.9-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 758820 bytes (741 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 741 Kb

package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpS0N9ok\downloaded_packages
> library("rJava", lib.loc="C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.0")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong here?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

My `R.Version()`:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "0.3"

$year
[1] "2014"

$month
[1] "03"

$day
[1] "06"

$`svn rev`
[1] "65126"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)"

$nickname
[1] "Warm Puppy"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem loading rJava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492361/problem-loading-rjava)

Comment: @EDi I tried the solution in this answer however I still get the same error ;(