# Failing to load rJava in RStudio

Tags: java, r, rstudio

So that I can use libraries dependent on rJava. When I try loading rJava, I get this:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object
```

'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found

So then I run

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

With this version of Java:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

Getting the following error:

```
trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -
I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
detected JNI linker flags : -framework JavaVM
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -
I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers  -
I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:4:5: warning: 'JNI_CreateJavaVM' is deprecated
  [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
JNI_CreateJavaVM(0, 0, 0);
^
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/jni.h:1937:1: note: 
  'JNI_CreateJavaVM' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);
```

Comment: use this post, by MRbee, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492361/problem-loading-rjava the problem is either a lack of Java, or that R cannot find the path to the java dll. use these directions to set your path!

Comment: The answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) may be helpful.

Comment: I think that my answer is more suitable here as it targets macOS which is the case in the question

Answer (score 0):

On macOS there are issues with Java, R, and RStudio configuration. I have struggled with this one for some time.

You can find some info here: [R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)

In general, you have to make sure to properly set Java, you need to enable JNI support for Java, you have to make sure to use Oracle's java instead of Apple's one (at least, for me, it's a preferred way of working with Java at macOS).