# Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object

Tags: r, dll, unc, tidyselect

I'm having this error when trying to attach package `tidyselect` and when trying to call `tidyselect::any_function`.

The error happens in `Rstudio` or command line alike, in `RStudio` it is triggered as soon as I type: `tidyselect::` , though `?tidyselect::` works fine and I can call the help of `?tidyselect::any_function`.

This also works:

```
packageVersion("tidyselect") # [1] ‘0.2.4
```

It used to work, and I don't understand what changed, I just know package `rjava` has been installed, the admins might also have changed something.

First a popup says:

> The procedure entry point R_ContinueUnwind could not be located in the dynamic link library R.dll

Then an Error is displayed in the console :

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
>
> unable to load shared object '//edited_UNC_path.com/edited_path/tidyselect/libs/x64/tidyselect.dll':
>
> LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

The `dll` file exists :

```
file.exists('//edited_UNC_path.com/edited_path/tidyselect/libs/x64/tidyselect.dll') # [1] TRUE
```

config :

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: I got a similar error when loading a DLL file that I had created. I rebooted R and this solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this event happens as I am currently facing the same problem. Anyways I can explain your solution.

## 32 vs 64 bits

Your system is 64 bits, as shown in your `sessionInfo()`. `i386` architecture is for the older systems, in 32 bits (they can only handle a limited amount of memory as they use 32 bits memory addresses, while 64 bits systems are, virtually, unlimited today).

## What happens in R

A classic installation in R is "multiarch" for multi-architectures, which means 32 and 64 bits. In 64 bits systems there is no problem in building a 32 bits software. However, your may not have all the dependencies (e.g. C++ libraries) installed for both architectures. There is apparently a problem with your 32 bits installation. Then installing the package with `INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch"` only installs the 64 bits version (the one you need), without problems.

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by reinstalling `tidyselect` using :

```
install.packages("tidyselect",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")
```

(Although the package could be install with `install.packages("tidyselect")` without error.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38254345/2270475) pointed me to the solution (totally different question though).

It seems that it was indeed an issue with `rjava`.

Quoting the linked answer:

> the solution was to use install option that simply forgets about i386 architecture. (also works with drat library and packages not from CRAN

It's all Chinese to me though and `?utils::install.packages` doesn't help, I'll happily upvote / accept an answer that explains what's going on.