# Rstan errors in R: Error in inDL & LoadLibrary failure

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I'm trying to run some rstan in RStudio from a class I'm taking, and the very first computer lab example won't work. My machine is a Windows 10, 64 bit on a Dell XPS 13 9360. I can run BRugs fine on RStudio, and that's mostly what I've been using, but I want to transition to using Stan instead.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      tidy = TRUE)
```
```{r}
library(rstan)
library(bayesplot)
```
````

And I get this output:

> Show in New Window package �rstan� was built under R version
> 4.0.5Loading required package: StanHeaders Loading required package: ggplot2 rstan (Version 2.21.2, GitRev: 2e1f913d3ca3) For execution on
> a local, multicore CPU with excess RAM we recommend calling
> options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()). To avoid recompilation of
> unchanged Stan programs, we recommend calling rstan_options(auto_write
> = TRUE) Do not specify '-march=native' in 'LOCAL_CPPFLAGS' or a Makevars file package �bayesplot� was built under R version 4.0.5This
> is bayesplot version 1.8.0
>
> - Online documentation and vignettes at mc-stan.org/bayesplot
> - bayesplot theme set to bayesplot::theme_default()    * Does *not* affect other ggplot2 plots    * See ?bayesplot_theme_set for details
>   on theme setting

But the problem is with this code

````
```{stan, output.var="binomial", label=ex1, cache=TRUE}
generated quantities{
  real y;
  real p;
  
  y = binomial_rng(8, 0.5);
  p = y <= 2;
}
```
````

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :    unable
> to load shared object
> 'C:/Users/Teresa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYde0OD/file23bc2f7df9e.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization
> routine failed. In addition: Warning message: In system(paste(CXX,
> ARGS), ignore.stdout = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) :   '-E' not found
> Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection Error in sink(type
> = "output") : invalid connection

I've searched for the error outputs but I can't find anything that helps. I tried `install.packages("rstan",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")` and `install.packages("bayesplot",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")` as suggested in
[Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150491/error-in-indlx-as-logicallocal-as-logicalnow-unable-to-load-share) but that didn't help (though maybe I should have uninstalled them first?). I'm very new to R and Stan, and I don't know what these errors are.

Comment: Uninstalling the packages first should not be necessary, but restarting R aftter installing with `--no-multiarch` would be a good idea.