# Unable to install R packages from source

Tags: r, rstudio, installation-package, rtools

I installed R a work administered computer (I don't have admin rights).
I also installed Rtools43.
When I try to install packages from source, I am consistently getting the error described below.

Details about system:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1
```

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/AdrianBlanco-Gomez/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/library"
```

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\rtools43\\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\\bin;C:\\rtools43\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\x64;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Users\\AdrianBlanco-Gomez\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\resources\\app\\bin\\quarto\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\resources\\app\\bin\\postback"
```

```
> Sys.which("make")
                              make 
"C:\\rtools43\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

Example of error:

```
> install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/AdrianBlanco-Gomez/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.8.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1053075 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'jsonlite' ...
** package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.2.0'
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c base64.c -o base64.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c collapse_array.c -o collapse_array.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c collapse_object.c -o collapse_object.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c collapse_pretty.c -o collapse_pretty.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c escape_chars.c -o escape_chars.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c integer64_to_na.c -o integer64_to_na.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c is_datelist.c -o is_datelist.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c is_recordlist.c -o is_recordlist.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c is_scalarlist.c -o is_scalarlist.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c modp_numtoa.c -o modp_numtoa.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c null_to_na.c -o null_to_na.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c num_to_char.c -o num_to_char.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c parse.c -o parse.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c prettify.c -o prettify.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c push_parser.c -o push_parser.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c r-base64.c -o r-base64.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c register.c -o register.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c row_collapse.c -o row_collapse.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c transpose_list.c -o transpose_list.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c validate.c -o validate.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl.c -o yajl/yajl.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_alloc.c -o yajl/yajl_alloc.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_buf.c -o yajl/yajl_buf.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_encode.c -o yajl/yajl_encode.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_gen.c -o yajl/yajl_gen.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_lex.c -o yajl/yajl_lex.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_parser.c -o yajl/yajl_parser.o
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"   -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c yajl/yajl_tree.c -o yajl/yajl_tree.o
ar rcs yajl/libstatyajl.a yajl/yajl.o yajl/yajl_alloc.o yajl/yajl_buf.o yajl/yajl_encode.o yajl/yajl_gen.o yajl/yajl_lex.o yajl/yajl_parser.o yajl/yajl_tree.o
gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o jsonlite.dll tmp.def base64.o collapse_array.o collapse_object.o collapse_pretty.o escape_chars.o integer64_to_na.o is_datelist.o is_recordlist.o is_scalarlist.o modp_numtoa.o null_to_na.o num_to_char.o parse.o prettify.o push_parser.o r-base64.o register.o row_collapse.o transpose_list.o validate.o -Lyajl -lstatyajl -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/AdrianBlanco-Gomez/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/00LOCK-jsonlite/00new/jsonlite/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"AsIs"': no definition for class "AsIs"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"ITime"': no definition for class "ITime"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"hms"': no definition for class "hms"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"json"': no definition for class "json"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"integer64"': no definition for class "integer64"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"pairlist"': no definition for class "pairlist"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"blob"': no definition for class "blob"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"scalar"': no definition for class "scalar"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"sf"': no definition for class "sf"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"sfc"': no definition for class "sfc"
in method for 'asJSON' with signature '"vctrs_vctr"': no definition for class "vctrs_vctr"
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'jsonlite' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/AdrianBlanco-Gomez/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/00LOCK-jsonlite/00new/jsonlite/libs/x64/jsonlite.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The parameter is incorrect.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/AdrianBlanco-Gomez/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/jsonlite'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/AdrianBlanco-Gomez/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/jsonlite'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\AdrianBlanco-Gomez\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGgX9Sq\downloaded_packages’
```

I have tried changing the folder where the packages are installed and the problem persists. Installing R in a folder where I have permissions does not solve it either. I also tried older versions of R and Rtools,
I do not know what else to try. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) have you checked out the answer from this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150491/error-in-indlx-as-logicallocal-as-logicalnow-unable-to-load-share

Comment: Here's another thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058317/4145280

Comment: @Mark Both errors appear to be unrelated (the first is specifically about a mismatch of the architecture, which seems to be consistently 64 bit for OP, and the second one is about missing permissions on the network attached filesystem, with a specific error message).

Comment: What error message are you getting from different packages? Are you also getting the shared object loading error “ LoadLibrary failure:  The parameter is incorrect.”? I am trying to exclude whether this is specific to ‘jsonlite’.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the feedback. The error "LoadLibrary failure:  The parameter is incorrect"  is exactly the same, with reference to different packages that I try to install from Source. It is not specific of `jsonlite`.

Comment: @r2evans I have tried restarting R and reinstalling it multiple times, It is not working, Again, this is not a specific problem of `jsonlite`, but from using `install.packages("any_package", type = "source")`

Comment: I mis-read it the first time, thinking the error was linking a different library to `jsonlite`, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an issue here (I'm no longer on windows), but I've always guarded against installing R into a directory that includes spaces (i.e., under `C:/Program Files/`). I know it often works just fine, but it's been an issue in many other ways often enough that when I ran windows, I always installed R under (e.g.) `C:/R/4.3.1/`. Just a thought in case everything else fails.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the issue persists when I install R directly `C:/R/4.3.1/`