# Are there any R packages to transform phones numbers in standard form?

Tags: r, transform, phone-number

I have a list of french phone numbers in different formats and interested in how to convert it into one "standard" format. According to Wikipedia "National conventions for writing telephone numbers" section each country has its own national and international formats for phones.

For example, in France

1. The national format common is "01 11 11 11 11"
2. The international format is "+33111111111". It makes by dropping "0" and spaces
   "+33 1 11 11 11 11" => "+33111111111"

It will be cool to know that exist R package that makes phones numbers normalization into predefined national/international formats

Answer (score 1):

The package [dialr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dialr) can do that. It is built around Google's *libphonenumber*. Furthermore, it requires rJava, which often seems to be problematic to get running (on Windows?), e.g., [Problem loading rJava](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492361/2563804).

Besides *libphonenumber*, there are other APIs listed here: https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis#data-validation. However, you may have to delevop the R interface yourself.